# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Commands which must be closed first

Tags: asp.net

It keep giving me

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

What is exactly wrong with my database code, can somebody help me?

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
          ["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    connect.Open();     

    string insertQuery = @"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Registration where Username=@Uname) insert into Registration (Username,Password,Phone,Email,Country) values (@Uname ,@Password ,@Phone ,@Email ,@Country)";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connect);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", name.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country.SelectedItem.ToString());
    SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();   

    if (sdr.HasRows) 
    {
    Response.Write("Username already exisited!");

}
else
{
    Response.Write("User name is available!");
}

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

connect.Close();
```

Comment: The issue seems obvious if you read the error message. You have an open data reader on the command, and then you call `ExecuteNonQuery` on the command. That clearly won't work. You only have a single statement, you just need to execute once.

Comment: why don't you use while(sdr.Read)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                    ["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    connect.Open();
    string insertQuery = @"IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Registration where Username=@Uname) insert into Registration (Username,Password,Phone,Email,Country) values (@Uname ,@Password ,@Phone ,@Email ,@Country)";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connect))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", name.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", Country.SelectedItem.ToString());
        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("User name is available!");                
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Username already exisited!");
        }
    }
}
```

You are calling SqlCommand twice when call ExecuteReader and when call ExecuteNonQuery. Due to your statement never returns records to client Property HasRows will be always false. And last it is recomended always use using statement when instantiating disposable object.